# Understanding the GR analogue of the first law of thermodynamic

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, energy-conservation

According to the book *Relativity, Thermodynamic and Cosmology* by Tolman, the general relativistic analogue of the first law of thermodynamics is given by:

$$\frac{\partial I^\mu_\nu}{\partial x^\nu}-\frac{1}{2} I^{\alpha\beta}\frac{\partial g_{\alpha\beta}}{\partial x^\mu}=0$$
$$(T^{\mu\nu})_{;\nu}=0$$

where  $I$ is the energy-momentum tensor density $$-8\pi I_{\mu\nu}(dg^{\mu\nu})= R_{\mu\nu}d(g^{\mu\nu}\sqrt{-g}).$$

What I do not understand from these equations is: what happens if there is energy loss, for example emission of radiation?

Does this form already includes this case?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as mentioned in the book you cited, $(T^{\mu\nu})_\nu=\nabla_\nu T^{\mu\nu}=0$ is nothing more than the conservation of energy-momentum. One could see it as *"the general relativistic analog of the first law of thermodynamics"* but I don't think this really adds any meaning to it.

To answer your question, **no**, these equations do not include the case of energy loss, or to better phrase it, they *include* it but do nothing to explain it.
The reason why is that in flat space $(\nabla\rightarrow\partial)$ the conservation of a tensor current $\partial_\nu T^{\mu\nu}=0$ can be seen as the generalization of the conservation of the more familiar vector current $\partial_\nu j^{\nu}=0$, meaning that they both lead to the conservation of a "charge" (energy, momentum, and angular momentum in the tensor case, and electric charge in the vector case). In curved space though, while the vector current still leads to the conservation of a charge (using the concepts of codifferential and generalized Stokes' Theorem) the tensor current has an extra term, dependent on the Christoffel's symbols, which means that there isn't a properly defined "charge", and so energy (in the non-gravitational sense) could be lost (we know that it isn't and that it just becomes gravitational energy, but gravitational energy isn't present in the energy-momentum tensor).